# When placing the results of a awk operation into a variable, my results are being overwritten

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bash script which will:

1. Call a python script called get-server-status.py
2. Pipe these results into an awk command which will get a commit-sha from this output
3. Put the final result into a variable called "SERVERS"

The python script which is called by my bash script returns the following:

```
2017-09-13 14:09:15 INFO: About to query Instance:i-01010abcde54345a4 
i-01010abcde54345a4 - 10.0.1.216: commit-sha = 0123456789
```

I wish to get only the characters after 'commit-sha' so I pipe this into awk with the following code:

```
GET_SERVER_STATUS="./get-server-status.py --field=commit-sha -a"
$GET_SERVER_STATUS $SERVER_ASG_NAME | awk -F "commit-sha = " '{ print $2 }
```

This returns what I want:

```
0123456789
```

Similarly, if my python script finds two servers and queries two instances...:

```
2017-09-13 14:09:15 INFO: About to query Instance:i-01010abcde54345a4 
i-01010abcde54345a4 - 10.0.1.216: commit-sha = 0123456789
2017-09-13 14:09:15 INFO: About to query Instance:i-03949eifje34543g3 
i-03949eifje34543g3 - 10.0.2.246: commit-sha = 0123456789
```

I get two commit shas. Just as I wanted:

```
0123456789   
0123456789
```

But here is where it goes wrong. If I try to put these results in a variable, i.e:

```
SERVERS=(`$GET_SERVER_STATUS $SERVER_ASG_NAME | awk -F "commit-sha = " '{ print $2 }'`)
```

It will only return one value instead of two.

```
0123456789
```

What is happening here? Is the first return of awk being overwritten when placed in a variable?

Comment: I guess you must make a [loop as parameter for awk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_loops.htm)

Comment: Related (for parentheses and how they're handled): ["How are parentheses interpreted at the command line?" on Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parentheses-interpreted-at-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bash's modern process substitution syntax `$( ... )` or the old process substitution with only backticks `` ` ... ` ``:

```
SERVERS=$( $COMMAND $ARGUMENTS | awk -F "commit-sha = " '{ print $2 }' )
```

What you wrote with `` (` ... `) `` runs the code inside the backticks and then creates a list/array (that's what the parentheses do) from its words. If you then try to read the array variable like a normal one, you will only get the first array element back. To get the others, you would have to specify an index.

```
$ text=(few words in here)
$ echo $text
few
$ echo ${text[1]}
words
```

---

I would also say that in this use case, `grep` with a look-behind probably is a more straight-forward solution, although your attempt with `awk` seems to be correct as well. It's mostly a matter of taste I guess, but here is what I would write instead:

```
SERVERS=$( $COMMAND $ARGUMENTS | grep -Po '(?<=commit-sha = )\w+' )
```

<sub>Note: I replaced your original variable names with shorter ones so that the commands nicely fit in one line.</sub>